# Show KMeans cluster results with clusters as columns

Tags: r, data-mining, cluster-analysis, k-means

My data has 40+ variables and I am creating a 3 cluster model on it.

I have built a kmeans model:

```
teen_clusters <- kmeans(interests_z, 3).
```

It works fine. It is getting an output that I can read is the issue.

When I screen print the model, it places the variables on the top (40 across) and the clusters as rows (3 deep). Very hard to read.

I want it the other way around. 3 cluster columns and 40 rows.

I have tried the below, but get the same thing. This does way too much screen wrap.

```
aggregate(interests_z,by=list(teen_clusters$cluster),FUN=mean)
```

Comment: use `dput(sample_data)` to give site users the opportunity to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How about **transposing** your data? The function `t` should be known to any R user ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we don't have your data lets use mtcars ...

```
ret <- kmeans(mtcars,3)

ret$centers       # the default format
t(ret$centers)    # transposed as you want
```

To see the components of ret use str(ret)